# A lightweight, native music player for Linux which integrates with Google Play

Tags: music, google-apps, arch-linux

I'm looking for native music clients for Linux which support integration with Google Play Music. Currently, I'm using the open-source Electron app [GPMDP](https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/), which is nice, but Electron apps are fairly heavy. This particular player spawns dozens of child processes when it runs, which persist (but don't multiply over time) until I quit the player; this ends up costing me a lot of RAM.

I'm indifferent about whether alternatives are GUI, or whether they have an `ncurses` CLI, or if they're even more barebones; as long as it can integrate with Google Play Music and it supports media keys under GNOME (either natively or with minor tweaks), it's a good-enough player.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [Nuvola Player](https://tiliado.eu/nuvolaplayer/)

It seems for me to not be using a lot of resources, and supports Google Play Music.

Answer (score -2):

If you are running chrome/chromium, you can download the Google play music app from the chrome store. It actually quite a handy player, and can be told to stay on top. The issue is that you (also) want your personal music. Luckily, you can actually upload your own music. On the the Play Music site, click the menu, then upload music. Then, just drag 'n' drop.

Comment: I've thought about it, but in my experience, it's also a fairly resource-heavy app. I'm also a Firefox user.

Comment: Huhhhhhh..... Can you grab URL'S For various Google play radios? I have an idea.

Comment: I don't think so, at least, not without dissecting Google Play's client-side source code.

Comment: Ah, damn. I'll keep looking then

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Would you mind improving this answer with screenshots, price information, download links. Or just delete this answer and write another one when you have found a great solution (but I think your answer would be worth something if improved). Cheers!

Comment: @NixolasRaoul Thanks for the welcome :) Just added a bit that should help (Huh, hyperlinks aren't working)